# Storing Poker Tournaments In Database SQL

Tags: t-sql

What would be the best way for storing many poker tournaments and player results with varying entrant sizes in a database? Some tournaments may have 500 people, other tournaments may have 5000 people. Will be storing each player to get various stats across tournaments as well as details of old tournaments and the results.

I was thinking of having a player table and a tournament table with a joiner table of one to many, but not sure this is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Each game has multiple players. right?  And each player can play multiple games in the same tournament, right? I also sounds like you might want to record multiple tournaments.  If so, you'd need at least three tables...

Comment: "Best way" questions aren't a very good fit here as they are almost always opinion-based and far too broad. Please review what is on topic in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

If each tournament has a number of games, first idea that comes to my mind is:

```
[tournament]: Master table for a tournament. Name, start date etc
[person]: Master table for people
[participant]: Join table of [tournament] and [person] (has FKs to these tables). Example of additional info is date of cancelation if a participant dropped
[game]: Master table for a specific game/round. Has FK to the [tournament] it is a part of
[game_participant]: Join table of [participant] and [game]. Can have the personal result, like "eliminated 4th in the game"
```

Example: Alice,Bob,Celeste,Darius,Electra,Frank took part in "The Awesome Poker Battle".
First day, [Alice,Bob,Celeste] played.Alice won,Bob was eliminated first,Celeste was eleiminated second
Second day, [Darius,Electra,Frank] played. Frank won,Darius was eliminated first,Electra second
Third day, Celeste and Frank battled it out. Frank won the game, and thus the tournament.

The data would be:

```
[tournament]
+-----+--------------------------+
| id  |           name           |
+-----+--------------------------+
| 1   | The Awesome Poker Battle |
+-----+--------------------------+

[person]
+----+---------+
| id |  name   |
+----+---------+
|  1 | George  |
|  2 | Alice   |
|  3 | Bob     |
|  4 | Celeste |
|  5 | Darius  |
|  6 | Electra |
|  7 | Frank   |
+----+---------+

[participant]
+-----+------------+--------+
| id  | tournament | person |
+-----+------------+--------+
| 102 |          1 |      2 |
| 103 |          1 |      3 |
| 104 |          1 |      4 |
| 105 |          1 |      5 |
| 106 |          1 |      6 |
| 107 |          1 |      7 |
+-----+------------+--------+

[game]
+-----+------------+
| id  |    date    |
+-----+------------+
| 200 | 2023-01-01 |
| 201 | 2023-01-02 |
| 202 | 2023-01-03 |
+-----+------------+


[game_participant]
+------+-------------+----------+
| game | participant | elim_ord |
+------+-------------+----------+
|  200 |           2 |        0 |
|  200 |           3 |        1 |
|  200 |           4 |        2 |
|  201 |           5 |        1 |
|  202 |           6 |        2 |
|  203 |           7 |        0 |
+------+-------------+----------+
```